# subtract second datetime row from first datetime row of a column if another column shows duplicate values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns Order date and Customer(which have duplicates of only 2 values which has been sorted), I want to subtract the second Order date of the second occurrence of a Customer from the first Order date. Order date is in datetime format
here is a sample of the table
context I'm trying to calculate the time it takes for a customer to make a second order\

```
Order date  Customer
4260    2022-11-11 16:29:00 (App admin)
8096    2022-10-22 12:54:00 (App admin)
996 2021-09-22 20:30:00 10013
946 2021-09-14 15:16:00 10013
3499    2022-04-20 12:17:00 100151
... ... ...
2856    2022-03-21 13:49:00 99491
2788    2022-03-18 12:15:00 99523
2558    2022-03-08 12:07:00 99523
2580    2022-03-04 16:03:00 99762
2544    2022-03-02 15:40:00 99762
```

I have tried deleting by index but it returns just the first two values.

expected output should be another dataframe with just the Customer name and the difference between the Second and first Order dates of the duplicate customer in minutes

expected output:

```
| Customer | difference in minutes |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1232     | 445.0   |
|(App Admin)| 3432.0   |
| 1145     | 2455.0   |
|6653     | 32.0   |
```

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: Umm... can you not just do `df.groupby('Customer')['Order date'].diff()` and then translate to the time units you want?

Comment: @JonClements. Using `diff` is like a `transform` operation not  an `aggregate` one. So you have to drop the `NaT` row then merge with the original dataframe because the index is not the Customer but the real index of original dataframe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
df['Order date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order date'])

out = (df.groupby('Customer', as_index=False)['Order date']
         .agg(lambda x: (x.iloc[0] - x.iloc[-1]).total_seconds() / 60)
         .query('`Order date` != 0'))
print(out)

# Output:
      Customer  Order date
0  (App admin)     29015.0
1        10013     11834.0
4        99523     14408.0
5        99762      2903.0
```